# Estou abusando muito do Strategy Pattern em Java?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Em uma aplicação para autenticação de usuários via Radius achei que seria interessante a utilização do Design Patter Strategy com Enum.

Então o código ficou desse jeito:

```
public enum TipoAutenticacao {

LIVRE("Acesso Livre"){
    @Override
    public String autentica(LoginService service, String user, String mac) throws NoResultException, AccessException{
        Login login = service.findByUser(user);
        return login.autentica(user, login.getPass());
    }
},
MAC("Filtro de MAC"){
    @Override
    public String autentica(LoginService service, String user, String mac) throws NoResultException, AccessException{
        Login login = service.findByUser(user);
        return login.autentica(user, login.getPass(), mac);
    }
};

private String descricao;


TipoAutenticacao(String descricao){
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public String getDescricao(){
    return this.descricao;
}

public abstract String autentica(LoginService service , String user, String mac) throws NoResultException, AccessException;
}
```

Método `autentica` no `Login`

```
    public String autentica(String user, String pass, String mac) throws AccessException {
    if(!this.mac.equals(mac))
        throw new AccessException(TipoLoginResposta.MAC_INVALID);

    return autentica(user, pass);
}

public String autentica(String user, String pass) throws AccessException {
    if(!this.user.equals(user) || !this.pass.equals(pass))
        throw new AccessException(TipoLoginResposta.USER_PASS_INVALID);
    if(bloqueado)
        throw new AccessException(TipoLoginResposta.BLOQUEADO);
    if(!this.getUsuario().isPendenciaFinanceira())
        throw new AccessException(TipoLoginResposta.PENDENCIA_FINANCEIRA);
    return this.pass;
}
```

`TipoLoginResposta`

```
public enum TipoLoginResposta {

USER_PASS_INVALID("Login/Senha Inválidos"),
MAC_INVALID("MAC Inválido"),
PENDENCIA_FINANCEIRA("Pendência Financeira"),
BLOQUEADO("Bloqueado");

private String descricao;

TipoLoginResposta(String descricao){
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public String getDescricao(){
    return this.descricao;
}
}
```

A ideia de utilizar o `AccessException` passando no construtor `TipoLoginResposta` é para que seja especificado mais tarde no banco de dados o motivo pelo qual o usuário não conseguiu se conectar.

Utilizando essa implementação eu estou amarrando o código de alguma maneira?

Comment: No caso de `TipoAutenticacao` se puder evitar ser um `enum` melhor, a meu ver bastam duas classes que implementam uma interface com o método `autentica()`.

Comment: Mas caso precise adicionar outras maneiras de autenticar? Eu teria que ter uma classe para  cada tipo de autenticação.. Isso geraria várias classes, não?

Comment: Geraria, assim como do jeito atual você precisaria de várias instâncias do enum TipoAutenticacao. Mas sem violar o princípio do aberto/fechado, pois não estaria alterando um enum e sim acrescentando classes.

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado à pergunta, mas por que você copia boa parte do código entre os `autentica` com 2 ou 3 parâmetros? Não seria melhor o com 3 parâmetros fazer algo como `{ if(!this.mac.equals(mac)) throw ...; return autentica(user, pass); }` A ordem dos testes ficaria ligeiramente alterada, entretanto, talvez não seja o que você precisa, mas fica aí como sugestão.

Comment: @Piovezan Obrigado! Vou considerar sua dica. Esse principio do aberto/fechado é o conceito do SOLID certo? vou da uma estudada nisso.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Realmente! eu apliquei isso em outras partes do código, mas deixei passar nessa parte. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Estou abusando muito do Strategy Pattern em Java?

A resposta é sim. Os padrões de projetos não devem ser utilizados inadvertidamente. Para o seu caso, você poderia ter resolvido o problema de maneira mais simples.

A implementação do autentica do `LIVRE` e do `MAC` é praticamente a mesma, você apenas adicionou mais um parâmetro.

Se um problema pode ser resolvido de maneira simples, ele deve ser resolvido de maneira simples. No seu caso, se cada tipo realmente tivesse uma implementação diferente e com o tempo novos tipos começassem a surgir e a manutenção começasse a ficar difícil, aí  sim entra o padrão de projeto para resolver a situação.
Apesar que da forma que você fez, toda vez que aparecer um tipo novo, você vai precisar alterar o `TipoAtenticacao`. A ideia do Strategy é justamente não precisar ter que fazer isso. A ideia é criar um classe nova e plugá-la ao sistema.